# IntelliJ replace variable names in multiple lines

Tags: java, replace, intellij-idea

I am wondering is there a shortcut that can replace a variable name with a new name on multiple lines in the current `Java` file for `IntelliJ`. Is it just simply doing a find and replace operation, but it can't really solve the problem obviously.

Comment: context menu => refactor => rename

Comment: It's been a while for me with IntelliJ, but don't you have the option to rename a field in the "refactor" menu?

Comment: try this Shift+F6

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/rename-refactorings.html?search=rename

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try to set cursor on variable and use shortcut <kbd>Shift-F6</kbd> - after that there are dialog frame for change name of variable and it changes all occurences of variable to setted name.

Also, you can use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-R</kbd> for replacing any word in project, it is useful if you working with huge project or your variable appears in config files.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1: Put the cursor on the variable
ex:

[image]

2. Press `shift+f6`
3. Enter the name you want in the appeared dialogue box

ex:

[image]

4. Hit the **Refactor** button

Answer (score 0):

Select your variable by right click > select refactor > rename

And rest all will be taken care by ide itself

[image]